# Should I use "that" in this situation?

Tags: word-usage, conjunctions, optional-that

My question is that which of the followings is correct?

- My question is [...]
- My question is that [...]

for example should I use that in the first sentence of this post or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conjunction *that* is never used in this context. You have a number of ways to express this question, but none of these ways employs the conjunction *that*.

- Which of the following is correct?
- My question is "Which of the following is correct?"
- I want to know which of the following is correct.
- Please tell me which of the following is correct.

You use the conjunction *that* with an indicative clause, not a question.

- I believed that both of the following are correct.
- He told me that only the first of the following is correct.
- I now know that only the first of the following is correct.

You may however use the demonstrative ('pointing') pronoun *that* with a question:

- **That** is what I want to know: which of the following is correct.
- I want to know **that**: which of the following is correct.
- I now know **that**: that only the first of the following is correct.

Comment: From NPR - *But my question is that for how long do you want to not to send a signal to Tehran...*

Comment: @MaulikV: haha politics again, but it seems a serious contradiction!

Comment: @MaulikV: The speaker there is non-native; listen to the [recording](http://www.npr.org/player/v2/mediaPlayer.html?action=1&t=1&islist=false&id=6860149&m=6860150), from about 8:40 forward. This is moreover a spoken context, in which even native speakers struggle to formulate their sentences. You will find on Google many instances of non-native speakers writing *my question is that*, and many instances of native speakers writing *my question is that* followed by a statement which acts as background to the question, before finally arriving at the question itself.

Comment: @StoneyB I see. To me, being an Indian, it sounded okay. I learn this now. Just tell me, if I use *my question is that...* and then statement, does it require question mark?

Comment: @MaulikV One of the most interesting questions for the next century will be which of Indian English's innovations Anglo-American English ends up adopting!

Answer (score 0):

Though both can be used to ask a question, there's something interesting.

When you use *that*, the sentence does not require *comma* in general and I think question mark is optional (I'll edit this if someone comments on it, to make this answer better). On the other hand, the sentence without *that* generally requires comma.

Check these -

> *My question is, how does it go there?* 
>   *My question is that how does it go there (?).*

Answer (score -2):

Both are correct. I think to use that in this case question of style. There are cases when using that is not valid. This case is not one of them.

Comment: Do you mean they are equal? I think the second one is a little more official, is this right?

Comment: I would say yes, they are, but it depends on the missing part of the sentence.